# app to deny all calls except contact list - how to create ? android 8

Tags: android

My current situation is that i have about 50 fake calls per day...and i am sick of it

I have some knowledge of C# and PowerShell so i think that i should try

So, i need to create android 8 app to deny ALL calls except from my contact list

I googled a lot and only i find is https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/block-numbers but that is not i want

As i understand it should be SERVICE in terms of android, but...but what API etc should i use ? Can android even do it ?

Many thanks !

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService

Comment: Many thanks. Thats what i need